# jqGrid Partial Text Search Not Working

Tags: jqgrid

I need to display a table from an SQL database with the following columns:
ID (integer, primary key)
Name (varchar)

I am using jqGrid 3.5.3. I am not allowed to update to a later version.

When I use jqGrid to search in the Name column, the search function only returns exact matches, not partial ones. Here is my code:

```
var mygrid = jQuery("#gridView").jqGrid({
            url: getRootPath() + 'dataHandler.ashx',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['ID', 'Name'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: '45', formatter: 'integer' },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: '200', editable: true, stype: 'text', edittype: 'textarea', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en']}},
           ],
            ignoreCase: true
        });
    mygrid.filterToolbar({ defaultSearch: "cn" });
    mygrid[0].toggleToolbar();
```

As you can see, I've tried both

```
sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en']
```

and

```
filterToolbar({ defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

Why isn't partial search functioning correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really use six years old version jqGrid 3.5.3 then the reason of your problem could be only in *your server code*. jqGrid send to the server just `Name=searchString` where the `searchString` part is the text typing by the user. **The server is responsible** for building case-insensitive `SELECT` with `LIKE` which uses the `searchString`. I suppose that your old code just uses fix `=` compare in the `SELECT` statement.